# VS2015 Cordova tools - Android device build errors

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, phonegap-build, jslint

I am using Apache Cordova tools in Visual Studio 2015 and I want to debug my app on an Anrdoid device.

When I debug my app using the Ripple emulator everything is working ok but when I run debug on an android device I get the following errors:

[image]

After researching the issue a little I found that these errors are JSLint errors. I thought there must be a way to supress these errors with Cordova Tools in VS > Tools > Options but could find anything relevant.

I also tried to change .jshintrc file and added :

```
eqeqeq : false
```

but that also didn't solve my problem. Is there a way to get rid of these errors?

I get about 110 errors like this so fixing all my code issues is a little problematic.

Comment: Have you tried /* jshint ignore:start */
     // Code Block
     /* jshint ignore:end */ to ignore the error?

Comment: @ElvisXia I added the comments but I am still getting the same errors

Comment: JSHint support 3 extensions for VS. See [this link](http://jshint.com/install/). what extension did you install for your Visual Studio?